# To access Tableview cell in Button action

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I want to delete tableview cell by clicking a button present in the same cell. But I am unable to access the cell in the button action function. 
Please help me to Access this cell. My code is -

```
class MatchesViewController: UIViewController{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MatchingUsersTVCell") as? MatchingUsersTVCell else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    let likeUid = userIdArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.heartBtn.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.heartBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender: UIButton){
        if let cell = sender.superview as? MatchingUsersTVCell{
            CellAnimator.animate(cell: cell)
        }
        let tag = sender.tag
        let userid = userIdArray[tag]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@objc func userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender: UIButton){

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: sender.convert(sender.frame.origin, to: tableView)) else {
        return
    }

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MatchingUsersTVCell
}
```

And in your `cellForRowAt` function add the following code:

```
cell.yourBtn.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.yourBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd stay away from using tags, and instead implement protocol/delegate.
Using indexPath allows use of multiple sections, etc...

1) Create a protocol:

```
protocol MatchingUsersTVCellDelegate : class {
    func didTapLikeButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
    func didTapOtherButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

2) Create/Update your cell:

```
class MatchingUsersTVCell : UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: MatchingUsersTVCellDelegate?   
    var indexPath: IndexPath!
    // add target to your like button
    func didTapLIkeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.didTapLikeButton(indexPath)
    }
    func didTapOtherButton() {
        self.delegate?.didTapOtherButton(indexPath)
    }
}
```

3) make sure your viewController conforms to the new delegate:

```
extension YourViewController: MatchingUsersTVCellDelegate {
    func didTapLikeButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Do something with the indexPath or indexPath.row
        dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
    func didTapOtherButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Do something else with the indexPath or indexPath.row
    }
}
```

4) Set delegate and indexPath

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell...
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the added benefit of creating a protocol here as opposed to selectors?

Comment: @DavidChopin For one, it's easier to reuse the cell in multiple vc's without having to check what the parentVC is.  If there is more than one section, tags won't work.   Thanks for the downvote though

Answer (score 0):

Within `MatchingUsersTVCell`, add two properties, one named `parentVC` of type `UIViewController` and one named `index` of type `Int`:

```swift
class MatchingUsersTVCell: UITableViewCell {
    var parentVC: UIViewController!
    var index: Int!

    ...

}
```

Then, when creating each cell, set these two values appropriately:

```swift
class MatchesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource {

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MatchingUsersTVCell") as? MatchingUsersTVCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.parentVC = self
        cell.index = index

        ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, you simply update your `parentVC`'s tableView's data source and reload its data whenever the button is tapped:

```swift
class MatchingUsersTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    ...

    @objc func userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender: UIButton){
        parentVC.userIdArray.remove(at: index)
        parentVC.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like this in your selector method

```
@objc func userLikeButtonWasTappaed(button:UIButton){
guard let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: button.convertPoint(button.frame.origin, toView: myTableView)) else {
    print("Error: indexPath)")
    return
}

print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```